Why is Cordova build android not working?
I’m trying to run Cordova build android , and it’s saying I should install android build tool v34.00 while I have v35 installed
FAILURE: Build failed with an exception.

Where:
Script 'C:\Users\LAPTOP\feazaa\platforms\android\CordovaLib\cordova.gradle' line: 73

What went wrong:
A problem occurred evaluating script.



No installed build tools found. Please install the Android build tools version 34.0.0.


Where are your build tools found? Also, did you add it to your PATH variable?
